# How to store IP-address of VM created by terraform in a text file

Tags: file-io, terraform, ip-address

I am creating a windows VM using vsphere plugin from terraform. I am fetching the IPaddress of the created VM.

```
output "ipv4" {
    value= vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.guest_ip_addresses[0]
}
```

this will flash the IPaddress on the commandprompt but I want to store this IPaddress in some file and want to use it another python function later on.
Can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [terraform output](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/output.html):

```
terraform output -json ipv4 > myfile.json
```